# Java JTextPane Markdown Formatting - Remove format-defining characters

Tags: java, swing, markdown

I'm adding markdown formatting to an instant messenger. I have it working with a JTextPane using this code:

```java
Matcher matcher;

        matcher = Pattern.compile("\\|`.+?`\\|").matcher(docContents);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            Document.setCharacterAttributes(matcher.start(), matcher.group().length(), BOLD, false);
        }
        matcher = Pattern.compile("\\*([^\\n*]+)\\*").matcher(docContents);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            Document.setCharacterAttributes(matcher.start(), matcher.group().length(), ITALIC, false);
        }
        matcher = Pattern.compile("__+([^\\n*]+)__+").matcher(docContents);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            Document.setCharacterAttributes(matcher.start(), matcher.group().length(), UNDERLINE, false);
        }
        matcher = Pattern.compile("~~+([^\\n*]+)~~+").matcher(docContents);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            Document.setCharacterAttributes(matcher.start(), matcher.group().length(), STRIKETHROUGH, false);
        }
```

However, I'm having the issue where formatted strings appear like this:

[image]

But i don't want the asteriskes to show up.

How would I remove them after having done the formatting?

Comment: Regular expression substitutions are not suitable for writing a parser.  What will your code do when it encounters this?   `ˋprintln("I *love* asterisks")ˋ`  (Also, Java code conventions state that variable names which are not constants should start with a lowercase letter.  This is especially important when you are using a name like `Document` which is the name of a Java SE class.)

Comment: @VGR It's not stdout formatting, it's for a JTextPane, as said in the title

Comment: Post an [mre] demonstating your problem.

Comment: Whether my example markdown snippet is calling println or any other function doesn’t matter.  What matters is that there’s asterisks inside back-quotes.  Inside back-quotes, neither asterisks nor any other characters should be treated as special.  Your code will incorrectly treat the back-quoted asterisks as italic markdown.